# Magento 2 with Porto theme Custom CSS from admin

Tags: magento2

Still learning Magento :)

I'm using Porto theme for my Magento 2 project and want to edit the css through:

`Stores > Configuration > Porto > Porto - Settings Panel > Customization`

They provided an area to put your css. But I'm not sure how to put image path for my background images **`background-image: url(???)`**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to link to the background image as the static content renders a different URL when the contents are cleared (for example when you run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`).

The best way to override or add CSS is by customizing the Porto theme's custom.css file in the Porto child theme. This way you can add a background image URL like `../images/foo.jpg`.